# Empty variable $name

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a request to db:

```
$str = "SELECT name FROM `student_info` WHERE code='$code'"; 
$name = $link->query($str) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

**$name** does not return anything

[this is a structure of a student_info table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3HiR.jpg)

Help Please!

Comment: there isn't enough code here. Post the relevant code or check for errors

Comment: *"Help Please!"* - How, guess what the variables are and their values? Not gonna happen.

Comment: What does `var_dump($name)` show?

Comment: @RogerNg why pray tell is there an error in the `WHERE` clause? what mistake is it? I sure don't see one.

Comment: Add this two lines before the line where you are creating the db connection: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, followed by `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Does an error mesage appear on screen? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM student_info WHERE code='$code'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     $name =  $row["name"];
    }
```